# Facebook DensePose

Tags: deep-learning, 3d-reconstruction

I was reading Facebook DensePose paper and i did not understand the method of choosing sampled points for each segmented part of a person in 2d image and getting correspondense on SMPL 3D model, i would like to know how did they decided for sampled points and did they give those points any identity for localization.

here is the link
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00434.pdf

Comment: could you provide a link to the referred paper?

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte sure, i edited the question, now you can get the link. Btw now i have understood the procedure they explained , still Thank you